# Buttons active state being overwritten in local storage with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple page that displays some buttons.

When a user clicks on one of the buttons, it turns blue and I want it to stay blue on reload.

As you can see in the homepage file, I am mapping over some simple data objects and creating a button for each piece of data.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../App.css";
import Button from "../components/Button";
import Data from "./../data.json";

function Home() {
  const [homeData] = useState(Data);

  return (
    <div className="featured-cards">
      {homeData.map((button) => {
        return <Button title={button.name} description={button.description} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

In the button component, I have set it to save the selected state in local storage.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Button(props) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setSelected(!selected);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = window.localStorage.getItem(`selected-${props.title}`);
    if (data !== null) setSelected(JSON.parse(data));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem(
      `selected-${props.title}`,
      JSON.stringify(selected)
    );
  }, [selected]);

  return (
    <button
      className={`button-${selected ? "selected" : "not-selected"}`}
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      <h3>{props.title}</h3>
      <p className="description">{props.description}</p>
    </button>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

When testing it, it changes the item from false to true in local storage when the button is selected, however, when I refresh, it is set back to false, here is a screenshot of local storage before refresh - https://gyazo.com/ce708ab9bbb5f01e2f45baf47afdd389 and after refresh - https://gyazo.com/d72a340ffe5efa87af0014cf8e388ac9

Answer (score 0):

You set the state to `false` by default so your hook changes it back to false.

Load the storage to state to fix it

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(localStorage.getItem(`selected-${props.title}`));
```

Comment: Ahh, knew it would be something so simple! Thanks